# SQL SERVER PROBLEMA COLLATION

Tags: sql-server

Alguém pode ajudar com esse Union de tabelas com collates, procurei no Google e não entendi muito bem.

> erro :   Cannot resolve the collation conflict between
>   "SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AI" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS"
>   in the UNION operation.

```
Select MAX(SERV_DH_ULTIMAATU) AS RECEBIMENTO ,EMPR_DS_EMPRESA, DATEDIFF(MI, MAX(SERV_DH_ULTIMAEXEC), GETDATE()) AS PERIODO
                             from  A1.DBO.CS_CDTB_SERVICO_SERV SERV (NOLOCK)
                             INNER JOIN   A1.DBO.CS_CDTB_EMPRESA_EMPR EMPR ON
                             EMPR.ID_EMPR_CD_EMPRESA = SERV.ID_EMPR_CD_EMPRESA
                             where SERV_DS_SERVICO LIKE '%AGENTE DO CLASSIFICADOR DE EMAIL%'    
                             AND EMPR.EMPR_IN_INATIVO = 'N'AND EMPR.EMPR_DS_EMPRESA NOT LIKE '%(NÃO USAR)%' 
                             GROUP BY EMPR_DS_EMPRESA union         

                               Select MAX(SERV_DH_ULTIMAATU) AS RECEBIMENTO ,EMPR_DS_EMPRESA, DATEDIFF(MI, MAX(SERV_DH_ULTIMAEXEC), GETDATE()) AS PERIODO
                             from  A2.DBO.CS_CDTB_SERVICO_SERV SERV (NOLOCK)
                             INNER JOIN   A2.DBO.CS_CDTB_EMPRESA_EMPR EMPR ON
                             EMPR.ID_EMPR_CD_EMPRESA = SERV.ID_EMPR_CD_EMPRESA
                             where SERV_DS_SERVICO LIKE '%AGENTE DO CLASSIFICADOR DE EMAIL%'    
                             AND EMPR.EMPR_IN_INATIVO = 'N'AND EMPR.EMPR_DS_EMPRESA NOT LIKE '%(NÃO USAR)%' 
                             GROUP BY EMPR_DS_EMPRESA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brian, provavelmente os dois bancos de dados estão em COLLATIONS diferentes.

Um está em `SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AI` e outro está em `SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS` (note os finais `AI` e `AS` que os diferencia no erro apresentado!).

Deste modo, ao realizar o UNION, o SQLServer não consegue unir tipos de Collations diferentes.

**Solução 1**

Altere o Collation de um dos bancos de dados para ser igual ao do outro.

**Solução 2**

Utilize `COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS` após cada campo do select para converte-los. Assim o UNION seria capaz de unir os campos. Deste modo:

```
SELECT
     EMPR_DS_EMPRESA COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS,
     CAMPO_2 COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
FROM A2.DBO.CS_CDTB_SERVICO_SERV
```

Referência: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25260659/collation-conflict-in-sql-union-all-query

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado